# Root Domain Query Strings Redirects?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've got a site with URL's like this:

http://www.example.co.uk/?attachment_id=364

These are being loaded using a carousel and when clicked actually load onto pages.

I can't seem to find a rewrite rule that will redirect the URL above to /cctv for example.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And just get rid of `attachment_id=364`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=364
RewriteRule ^ cctv? [L,R]
```